# JSP using URL parameter as array index

Tags: jsp

This seems like quite a simple problem, but after spending half an hour reading SO and other various sites I still haven't been able to come across a solution.

I'm trying to get a parameter from my URL to use as an index to display an array item:

This will display my first element of the array (a list of products):

```
<c:out value="${applicationScope.productList[0]}"/>
```

And I can get the index in the form of a string via a URL parameter:

```
<%= request.getParameter("item") %>
```

I'm not sure if the next line is relevant, but I am able to convert the string to an int:

```
<%int no = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("item")); %>
```

But I am unable string these together to turn that parameter value into an int and replace the "0" in the first line of code with the parameter so I can dynamically load content in the page.

I thought the following would have been the solution, but it isn't even syntactically correct so I'm out of ideas (EDIT: missed the closing % in the original post. Edited accordingly).

```
<%int no = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("item")); %>
<c:out value="${applicationScope.productList[ <%=no%> ]}"/>
```

The error received is

> /bookDetail.jsp (line: 16, column: 1) "${applicationScope.productList[<%=no%>]}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${applicationScope.productList[<%=no%>]}]

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *param* variable in **EL**(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm) to get value of request parameter. I haven't check but I think that conversion from String to int will be done automaticaly by **EL**. As a result you can write:

```
<c:out value="${applicationScope.productList[param.parameter]}"/
```

Where 'parameter' is the name of the param you want - such as param.item, param.mobile, param.page, etc.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I think I misinterpreted your answer at first - but what specifically worked for me was putting param.item as the array index, I guess the string was automatically coerced into an int. I've edited the response to reflect that in case anyone stumbles across this thread seeking the same help. I'll mark your response as accepted.